# Access Firebase unique ids within ng-repeat using angularFire implicit sync

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a list of objects from Firebase using the `angularFire` implicit data sync, and I'd like to render their unique ids (for use in urls) along with the other data properties using `ng-repeat`. Can I make `angularFire` return in such a way that I have access to the object ids within `ng-repeat`, the same way that members of an `angularFireCollection` have an `$id` property? If not, what is the right way to accomplish this? Hypothetical code (that doesn't work):

**Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('ItemListCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
  function ItemListCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
    angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items');
  }
]);
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" >
  <a href="" ng-href="#/items/{{item.name()}}">{{item.text}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think all you need is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, item) in items">
  <a href="" ng-href="#/items/{{name}}">{{item.text}}</a>
</div>
```

The anglularFire object behaves just like a normal javascript object.

Comment: Ahhhrrrrggggg! Have been struggling with this forever until I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: They need to document this better -_-

Answer (score 7):

To get the unique ID that is created via the angularfire $add method, you can use the $id property:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" >
  <a href="" ng-href="#/items/{{item.$id}}">{{item.text}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working any longer. bennlich's answer does work though.

Comment: vice-versa for me, bennlich's method does not work, this one does. :P

Comment: vice-versa for me too :) .$id did the trick! especially in firebaseArrays :)