# Search information by user on firebase

Tags: search, firebase

This is probably very simple ,so sorry... 
I'm trying to create an application where i can create users and store informations by Firebase. There is an example here :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/11/1426182307-log.png

But now I want to check if the name already exists if someone wants to create a new user.

How would I go about grabbing individual user information without knowing their id , like simplelogin:54?

I've found this topic [Get users by name property using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963776/get-users-by-name-property-using-firebase) but it is not the same thing because in my case I don't know the children after "Users"

Cheers,

Comment: What *do* you know about the user? You must know *something* to be able to look them up.

Answer (score 1):

Like Frank said, you must know something about the user to be able to look her/him up.

However, here is a general answer. I am assuming that by "name" you mean the property "identifiant" that you've created.

## Suggestions

- Start by looking over the [Firebase Query documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/).

---

## Short Answer

1. To check if a user exists by the `identifiant` property, you'd `orderByChild("identifiant")` and query for a specific user with the `.equalTo("<identifient_here>")`.

For example, to check if a user with identifient="aaa",

```js
var usersRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/Users");
var identifient = "aaa";
usersRef.orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo(identifient).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Loaded user by identifient:",identifient,snapshot.val());
});
```

2. If instead you want to query by the key (such as `simplelogin:53`), you could query by using `orderByKey()` instead of `orderByChild()`... or just simply setting the ref to the user's key like so:

```js
var userKey = 'simplelogin:53';
var userRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/Users" + userKey);
userRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Loaded user",snapshot.val());
});
```

---

## Long(er) Answer

- You can handle this with a user factory (see [Angular Providers documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)).
- You return a promise in the factory using the `$q` service.
- Here is the  [Angular API documentation for `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

### Example with UserFactory

- Check out this working [PLNKR example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaZBjt5wTdcl1V8LNt2Z?p=preview).
- It's tied to one of my public Firebase instances.
- I created the same `simplelogin:53` user in `/Users` like you have.
- If you search for the `identifient` = `aaa`, you'll get the right user.
- *The controller implementation here is for example purposes, and doesn't really do anything worth while. It's just for reference.*

#### The Data

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "simplelogin:53" : {
      "identifiant" : "aaa"
    }
  }
}
```

#### UserFactory

```js
.factory('UserFactory', function($q, $firebaseObject, fbUrl){
  return function(userId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (userId.isNotEmpty()) {
      var userRef = new Firebase(fbUrl + '/Users/').orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo(userId);
      userRef.once("value", 
        function(dataSnapshot){
          if (dataSnapshot.val()) {
            console.log("Loaded user",dataSnapshot.val());
            deferred.resolve(dataSnapshot.val());
          } else {
            console.info("Couldn't find user by id",userId);
            deferred.reject("No user found by identifient = '"+userId+"'");
          } 
        },
        function(error){
          console.error("Error loading user",error);
          deferred.reject(error);
        }
      );
    } else {
      deferred.reject("No id entered!");
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
})
```

#### Controller

```js
.controller('HomeController',function($scope, UserFactory) {
  $scope.identifient = '';
  var showError = function(errorMessage) {
    if (errorMessage) {
      showUser(false);
      $scope.error = errorMessage;
    } else {
      delete $scope.error;
    }
  }
  var showUser = function (userObject) {
    if (userObject) {
      showError(false);
      $scope.user = userObject; 
    } else {
      delete $scope.user;
    }
  }
  $scope.loadUser = function() {
    var userPromise = new UserFactory($scope.identifient);
    userPromise.then(function(data){
      showUser(data);
    }).catch(function(error){
      showError(error);
    });
  }
 })
```

#### Template

```html
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
  <h2>Home Template</h2>
  <input ng-model="identifient" placeholder="identifient"/>
  <button ng-click="loadUser()">Find User</button>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-if="user">User: {{user}}</div>
  <div ng-if="error">Error: {{error}}</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Hope that helps.

Comment: Whaou, thanks a lot! It helps!
But I may have not be clear enough. In fact I want to check the contact's name of a user : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/11/1426336575-capture.png

When a user is log, and want to ee his contacts, I don't know how I can link the firebase ID with the name of a user's friend. 
 In this example , simplelogin:53 have simplelogin:54 as friend. How can I have the name of all simplelogin:53's friends?

Comment: My  controller :

f (authData) {
            console.log("Logged in as:",authData.uid);
            var friends = Db.ref.child("Users").child(authData.uid).child("Contacts").child("Friends");

            var obj= $firebaseObject(friends);

.... what do I do now?

Comment: You can do that with a [`Query`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/), assuming your security rules allow for it. Check out the documentation for [`.orderByChild()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html) and [`.equalTo()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html)