# How to get user id from a given mail

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to get the user ID when I input the mail of the user.

Is it possible?

Of course I have an authenticated user who is asking for the mail of a user already created.

I want to retrieve users like

```
var refer = firebase.auth ().ref ('test@test.com')
  refer.on ('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log (snapshot.val());
  })
```

But in a possible way.

Comment: `firebase.auth ().ref ('test@test.com')` I don't think that is the `auth` service has a `ref()` method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.

Comment: Aside from that: there is no API to look up the uid of a user based on their email address in Firebsae Authentication. If you need that functionality, you'll need to store the mapping yourself  ; for example in the Firebase Database.

Comment: Yep, I finally did exactly that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Store the user info you want on a separate node in your database structure, then when the user asks for that, you retrieve from that endpoint.

See these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965065/1757321
- [How do I link each user to their data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase)

Comment: I just edited the question, I don't think you understood right.