# unique property in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unique-constraint

I have an IOS app which contains categories. My storage on Firebase looks like this:

```
-root
   -Categories
      -key
        - color:
        - name:
        - sum:
   -Expenses
      -key
        -amount: 
        -category: 
        -date: 
        -description: 
        -initiator: 
        -name:
```

User must not add a category twice. I want to make category name unique. Is it possible to do in Firebase?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to ensure **unique values** in the Firebase Database.

But on the other hand **keys are always unique** within their context.

You can make use of this to model your data in such a way that it guarantees uniqueness of the property you want. Say you want the category name to be unique, store the categories under their name:

```
-Categories
  -name
    - color:
    - sum:
```

With this structure you're guaranteed to have unique category names.

If you must store the categories under their current keys, but still want to ensure unique names. You can create a secondary index, which uses the category names as keys to ensure their uniqueness.

```
-Categories
  -key
    - color:
    - name:
    - sum:
-CategoryNames
  -name: key
```

This latter approach is explained further in Kato's answer to [Enforcing unique usernames with Firebase simplelogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970681/enforcing-unique-usernames-with-firebase-simplelogin/29983839#29983839)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that if the same category is already there or not. Create a search with the specific category values (`where clause`) if there is already a category with the values don't add it. For how to search a specific result with firebase, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965065/2246798