# How to implement unique constraint on a child value of a node in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have to store students information having roll number attribute.I want to prevent users to enter duplicate roll number.So guide me how can I implement logic to ensure **rollno** to be unique. Image to reflect tree is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Use random number to generate roll number of each student

Comment: Sir! These roll numbers are not system generated, these are entered by students explicitly.My motive is to learn about unique constraint on 'roll_no' child  of all nodes of1th_role.

Comment: Another option could be to change your datastructure to have a list of roll numbers (as keys) with userid as value

Comment: Making a property value unique requires that you: 1) add a data structure where you use those values as the keys (this automatically ensures they're unique), 2) use a transaction or multi-location update when updating these value. For more on this see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35243492, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41443767, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25294478, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39149216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_detail").child("1th_role");
ref.orderByChild("roll_no").equalTo(number_entered).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  if(dataSnapshot.exist() {

       Toasty.makeText(Activity_Name.this,"Number already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
     else{
            //add data
         }

    }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

Since the student will enter the number, then do a query `orderByChild("roll_no").equalTo(number_entered)` that checks if the roll number that is entered already exists in the database.

Comment: Thanks  a lot .It works for me.But Sir is there any way to implement  constraints on a child on server side. Instead of checking for child on client side.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a constraint?

Comment: Sir! I have worked on mysql. And as we specifiy unique value constraint on  a table field while creating a table that is why I expecting that feature in firebase.

Comment: oh okay, yes there is no concept of primary key/unique constraint in firebase. It is also nosql