# Firebase Update Instance If The Value Exist

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update an instance in realtime DB if the value exist
If in realtime DB have a same date with today, push the new data inside the resi
So each date have a lot of array inside the resi
I tried this thing, it created a new instance inside the db

```
firebase
        .database()
        .ref('resi-list')
        .orderByChild("date")
        .equalTo(moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'))
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.val()) {
            firebase
              .database()
              .ref('resi-list')
              .child(snapshot.val().key)
              .update({
                resi: [{
                  noResi: resiForm.noResi,
                  type: resiForm.type,
                }]
              })
              .then(res => AlertInfo('Success', 'Success Post Data!', 'success'))
              .catch(err => AlertInfo('Oops', 'Error Post Data!', 'Error'));
          } else {
            firebase
              .database()
              .ref(`resi-list`)
              .push({
                date: moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'),
                resi: [{
                  noResi: resiForm.noResi,
                  type: resiForm.type,
                }],
              })
              .then(res => {
                AlertInfo('Success...', 'Success Post Data', 'success');
                fetchResiList();
              })
              .catch(err => AlertInfo('Oops', 'Error Post Data', 'Error'));
          }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

[image: DB Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want a certain value to be unique in the Realtime Database, you should use it as the key of a node.** That is the only way to guarantee uniqueness.

---

So instead of storing your date as a property under the `0`, use it as the key like this:

```
resi-list: {
  "2021-08-06": {
    resi: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now each data can only occur once under `resi-list`. In addition I changed your date format, to make sorting and filtering on it easier.

---

If you also want the `noResi` value to be unique under the `resi` of each date, you'd do the same there and use th `noResi` value as the key of those nodes:

```
resi-list: {
  "2021-08-06": {
    resi: {
      "EX102039-48576": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Also see:

- [unique property in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443767/unique-property-in-firebase)
- [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique)
- [Firebase security rules to check unique value of a child #AskFirebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase/39151205#39151205)